# rrdtool: Use Consulidation-Function MIN, exclude NaN Values

Tags: average, nan, minimum, rrdtool, consolidation

i have an archive which contains the minimum duration times of messages going through an enterprise service bus.

During night-time or on weekends it is possible, that there are no messages, so the minimum duration time is NULL. Because of this, i write NaN into my rrd-db.

If i now want to consolidate an archive with the MINIMUM-Function over 6 hours, i get a problem if in this 6 hours there is a NaN-Value. Because then the whole 6-hours timeframe will be saved as NaN.

**Is there any option to use a MINIMUM-Function, which ignores NaN-Values?**

*(Replacing NaN-Values with 0 would distort my graphs and is therefore not a good solution.)*

Any help is very appreciated. Thank you in advance for participating!

Comment: I have the same requirement for the AVERAGE-Function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution by myself. I haven't looked exactly enough at the documentation.
To ignore NaN / Unknown values, you have to use the xff (xfiles factor). With a xff of 0.99, the NaN values will be ignored by the consolidation function.

http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdcreate.en.html

> RRA:AVERAGE | MIN | MAX | LAST:xff:steps:rows
>
> xff The xfiles factor defines what part of a consolidation interval
>   may be made up from *UNKNOWN* data while the consolidated value is
>   still regarded as known. It is given as the ratio of allowed *UNKNOWN*
>   PDPs to the number of PDPs in the interval. Thus, it ranges from 0 to
>   1 (exclusive).